# How do I include a link with my directory images?

Tags: php, html, css

Here is a code I got:

```
<?
include "top.php";
?>
<center>
<a href='upload.php'><button>Upload Image</button></a>
</center>
<br>

<?php


$www_root = 'http://annexsecurity.x10.mx/images';
$dir = 'images/';
$file_display = array('jpg', 'jpeg', 'png', 'gif');

if ( file_exists( $dir ) == false ) {
   echo 'Directory \'', $dir, '\' not found!';
} else {
   $dir_contents = scandir( $dir );

    foreach ( $dir_contents as $file ) {
       $file_type = strtolower( end( explode('.', $file ) ) );
       if ( ($file !== '.') && ($file !== '..') && (in_array( $file_type,      $file_display)) ) {
          echo '<img src="', $www_root, '/', $file, '" alt="', $file, '"/>';
       }
    }
}
?>

<style type="text/css">

  img {
    height: 100;
    width: 100;
    float: left;
    margin: 0.5em;
    border: 1px solid #ccc;
    padding: 1em;
    font-size: 10px;
  }

</style>
```

What I am trying to do is make it so when you click on the image it leads you to a bigger version of the image. Like, the full image. for example, it would lead to something like: http://www.example.com/image.png/

Can somebody please help me with this? This is the line of code that displays the image:

```
echo '<img src="', $www_root, '/', $file, '" alt="', $file, '"/>';
```

Now, I want the link thing there so it will lead to the bigger image.

Comment: in order to turn images into links use a syntax similar to: <a href=#><img src=example.jpg></a>

Comment: you want to redirect users to a page that has an image bigger than the initial one or you want to pop-out the bigger version of the initial image on the same page?

Comment: you can also achieve this "effect" by adding an click event to the image. (jquery)

Answer (score 0):

You can link to an image `<a href="http://example.com/image.png"><img src="imageSrcHere" alt="" /></a>`

```
if ( file_exists( $dir ) == false ) {
   echo 'Directory \''. $dir. '\' not found!';
} else {
   $dir_contents = scandir( $dir );

    foreach ( $dir_contents as $file ) {
       $file_type = strtolower( end( explode('.', $file ) ) );
       if ( ($file !== '.') && ($file !== '..') && (in_array($file_type,$file_display)) ) {
          $imageLink = 'http://example.com/image.png'; //please write image url here.
          echo '<a href="'.$imageLink.'"><img src="'. $www_root. '/'. $file. '" alt="'. $file. '"/></a>';
       }
    }
}
```

Comment: correct...however this does not answer the op's question... He asked "How can i add a link to an image?" (approx.)

Comment: Because echo is being used comas are fine -- they are treated as separate parameters instead of concatenation. http://www.electrictoolbox.com/php-echo-commas-vs-concatenation/